# Python import packages under chroot environment

Tags: python

I am writing some Python script and I would like to use `os.chroot` to execute some code under chroot environment.  The problem is after calling `os.chroot`, paths in `sys.path` lie outside of the chroot jail, so `import` won't work.  What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all necessary imports before os.chroot.